# Using str_detect() rowwise with dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe with dplyr::mutate().
There are two cases for the column the data is taken from:

1. The original column ('cabin') contains **one** combination of letter and digits, e.g. 'E4'. In this case the new column should be 'E'.
2. The original column contains **two ore more combinations** of letter and digit, e.g. 'F G73' or 'B57 B59 B63 B66'. In this case the new column should be 'F,G' or 'B', respectively.

Data sample:

```
structure(list(pclass = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), survived = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), name = c("Allison, Miss. Helen Loraine", "Anderson, Mr. Harry", 
"Andrews, Miss. Kornelia Theodosia", "Moen, Mr. Sigurd Hansen", 
"Soholt, Mr. Peter Andreas Lauritz Andersen"), sex = c("female", 
"male", "female", "male", "male"), age = c(2, 48, 63, 25, 19), 
    sibsp = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), parch = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), ticket = c("113781", "19952", "13502", "348123", "348124"
    ), fare = c(151.55, 26.55, 77.9583, 7.65, 7.65), cabin = c("C22 C26", 
    "E12", "D7", "F G73", "F G73"), embarked = c("S", "S", "S", 
    "S", "S"), boat = c("", "3", "10", "", ""), body = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 309L, NA), home.dest = c("Montreal, PQ / Chesterville, ON", 
    "New York, NY", "Hudson, NY", "", ""), title = c("Miss.", 
    "Mr.", "Miss.", "Mr.", "Mr.")), row.names = c("3", "6", "7", 
"1025", "1218"), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code I use:

```
titanic_data <- titanic_data %>%
  mutate(cabin_zone = ifelse(str_detect(cabin," "),
                             cabin %>%
                               str_extract("[A-Z]") %>%
                               str_split(.," ") %>%
                               unlist(.) %>%
                               unique(.) %>%
                               paste(.,collapse = ","),
                             gsub("[0-9 ]", "", cabin)))
```

The results are fine for the second case, but the for the first case I always get this string as result: 'B,C,E,D,A,NA,T,F,G'.

I can't figure out why the operation isn't working as I want it to! Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you include a sample of data that we could run to test? Please run `dput(titanic_data)` and paste the output into the data to the body of your question if it's not too long. Or `dput(titanic_data[c(1,5,7),])` if, for instance, rows 1, 5, and 7 have relevant examples.

Comment: Added some sample data!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key problem you're facing is that `cabin %>% str_extract()...` is taking the whole column to evaluate for every row and extracting only the first relevant letter for each passenger. `str_extract_all` extracts each occurrence in each row and returns a list of character vectors (which needs collapsed). This should work instead:

**Edited to ensure compatible with tibbles:**

```r
library(tidyverse)

titanic_data %>%
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(cabin_zone = str_extract_all(cabin, "[A-Z]") |> 
           lapply(unique) |> 
           vapply(paste, character(1), collapse = ", ")) |> 
  select(name, cabin, cabin_zone)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   name                                       cabin   cabin_zone
#>   <chr>                                      <chr>   <chr>     
#> 1 Allison, Miss. Helen Loraine               C22 C26 C         
#> 2 Anderson, Mr. Harry                        E12     E         
#> 3 Andrews, Miss. Kornelia Theodosia          D7      D         
#> 4 Moen, Mr. Sigurd Hansen                    F G73   F, G      
#> 5 Soholt, Mr. Peter Andreas Lauritz Andersen F G73   F, G

# Selected some columns for simplicity
```

The functions `lapply` and `vapply` make the `unique` and `paste` functions work across each row individually (by iterating through a list of matches). If you prefer tidyverse `map` functionals you can compose these steps to return a character column using:

```r
titanic_data %>%
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(cabin_zone = str_extract_all(cabin, "[A-Z]") |> 
           map_chr(compose(\(x) paste(x, collapse = ", "), unique))) |> 
  select(name, cabin, cabin_zone)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   name                                       cabin   cabin_zone
#>   <chr>                                      <chr>   <chr>     
#> 1 Allison, Miss. Helen Loraine               C22 C26 C         
#> 2 Anderson, Mr. Harry                        E12     E         
#> 3 Andrews, Miss. Kornelia Theodosia          D7      D         
#> 4 Moen, Mr. Sigurd Hansen                    F G73   F, G      
#> 5 Soholt, Mr. Peter Andreas Lauritz Andersen F G73   F, G
```

Or you can use `rowwise()` to process each row in isolation and collapse them from there:

```r
titanic_data |>
  as_tibble() |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(cabin_zone = str_extract_all(cabin, "[A-Z]") |> 
           unlist() |> 
           unique() |> 
           paste(collapse = ", ")) |> 
  select(name, cabin, cabin_zone)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   name                                       cabin   cabin_zone
#>   <chr>                                      <chr>   <chr>     
#> 1 Allison, Miss. Helen Loraine               C22 C26 C         
#> 2 Anderson, Mr. Harry                        E12     E         
#> 3 Andrews, Miss. Kornelia Theodosia          D7      D         
#> 4 Moen, Mr. Sigurd Hansen                    F G73   F, G      
#> 5 Soholt, Mr. Peter Andreas Lauritz Andersen F G73   F, G
```

Comment: Thanks! And is there a way to use the str_extract_all() on every row without lapply() and vapply()?

Comment: Yes sorry there's also `rowwise` which would process each row individually (see third example I've just added above). `str_extract_all` still returns a list of length 1 for each column which needs `unlist`ed as your code above. This perhaps makes it more readable!